Local images is not in backend in backend after making dist file moving to backend
Local images is not showing after running backend server, after making dist folder and moving to backend
(https://i.sstatic.net/DdMcLAV4.jpg)
Before
(https://i.sstatic.net/XIdDO4Oc.jpg
After
(https://i.sstatic.net/JfByRZ32.jpg)
I tried many way like changing the path using webpack , changing syntax in src but nothing was helpful
